# Why don't my dual monitors powersave right when dual booting?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, multi-boot

I am currently running a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my Laptop and
now I am trying to connect another monitor for work. The problem is that my monitor (LG W1952QT) works when I boot Ubuntu but does not display and goes right into powersave mode when I boot windows 7. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a laptop?  If so, remember to set the output mode to your digital video out.  There's a button or fn-button to set it.  Most laptops have 3-4 modes:

1. built-in LCD
2. S-Video out
3. 15-pin (analog) out
4. DVI/HDMI out

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to get dual monitors working in Windows than it is in Linux.

What happens if you plug it in after Windows has started? If nothing, try pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Eh. `xrandr` is actually a really simple tool, once you wrap it with a little bit of Python ;)